# Simulation is the same as my thinking,but different from the pape r(charging loop)

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, wave

This question has already perplexed me for a long time ,after simulating it, the simulation is the same as my thinking,but different from the paper.So now i am confused who is right.

[image]

There is energy in the inductor,and when SW1 is closed,the current will flow through the diode,and charge the battery,then precharge the C1 to -\$V_{PD}\$.And the current source will charge the C1 from -\$V_{PD}\$ to  -\$(V_{PD}+V_{OC})\$.

[image]

Here is the waveform of proposed schematic

[image]
(SW1=SW3)Here is the waveform i build as a concerned citizen said,but i didn't use the ideal switch,i make a new one.And this schematic is much different from his.So i modify some parameter.

[image]
(SW1=SW3) For this schematic,i modify C1 from 15n to 60n,Cbatt from 2V to 1V,and as we can see,it is more similar to his,however,it still didn't precharge,but his did.

[image]

Here is the schematic i made

The reason i wonder the whether ideal switch has direction or not is because i don't know what is the loop for precharge the C1 to positive or negative voltage first.

Paper link:http://rincon-mora.gatech.edu/publicat/cnfs/new16_pzdamp.pdf

SW1 and SW2 (in the wave)is corresponding to SW1 and SW4 in the schematic,and SW3 (in the wave) is corresponding to SW2 in the schematic .on for connected,off for disconnected.

About the diode,i use the NMOS (draon connect with gate) to replace it

The reason for ours simulation are no the same maybe because of that switch,my switch is transmission gate switch .The first picture below is the TG switch,and  the second picture just an inverter,which in the TG switch.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting- Can you include a link to the paper?  Or the title and author if it's not publicly available to link?

Comment: @JohnD OK I add it

Comment: D1 is described as a synchronous element, not an actual diode.  What happens if you apply an initial condition of say 2V to the capacitor?

Comment: And what does the inductor current look like vs. time?

Comment: that 2V is not applied by us,it is precharged

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just wondered what would happen if you started the sim with with the cap pre charged.  If the inductor current is not discontinuous then it may take many cycles to get to the point where the circuit can pre-charge the cap on its own.  I have not had time to analyze it at all so I’m just throwing out ideas.

Comment: i add the inductor current,but did't precharge the capacitor with vdc or vpulse

Comment: I quote from the paper, "Note, by the way, DN is in practice switch that operates like a diode, so DN drops millivolts when conducting." So are you sure you have used non-ideal diode model? ... Further, the circuit in the paper seems to be grounded, while yours is not. This might be a reason!

Comment: I saw you [post this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368658/two-simulations-are-different-mine-v-s-papers) before, it seems like you haven't really listened and are really dependent upon asking for help. You should make a bit more effort when asking a very similar question, it looks like you didn't even try to use the previous answer.

Comment: @Hazem no that is not the reason,I also add the gnd in my simulated schematic,and the wave is very similar to the simulation without gnd ,and i don't know how to use the ideal diode in virtuoso cadence,it always said i need a diode name,but after naming it,it said that name isn't defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368658/two-simulations-are-different-mine-v-s-papers) didn't seem to help, as I see you stil are using pulse widths that are too large for what's described in the paper, and their periods are different.

> S<sub>PG</sub> and S<sub>G</sub> close at the end of the positive half-cycle across a quarter resonance period 0.25\$\tau_{LC}\$

The names are from the paper, fig. 6. I'm not sure why you made up that control pulse like you did (also from a [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369456/making-a-square-wave-which-has-two-different-kinds-of-pulse-width)), I couldn't find specifications like those in the paper. Since L=300\$\mu\$ and R=1, 0.25\$\tau\$=75\$\mu\$, so the pulse width should be about 75\$\mu\$s and the period 10ms. The current source has a period of 20ms, and the amplitude is small, I chose 5\$\mu\$A.

I didn't read all the paper, so I didn't find the timings for the second switch (S<sub>P</sub>, same paper, same figure), but, judging by the waveforms, it's offset by half a control period, 5ms, and the width kept short enough to allow discharging and charging with ease, here ~1ms. Rise and fall times are 1\$\mu\$s for both.

The diode here is a quasi-ideal one, you can concoct one from a PMOS, or similar, controlled by the discharge of the L, above S<sub>G</sub> (not by directly tying the gate), or maybe a switch like the other three, but you'll need a separate control pulse.

Here's what came up in LTspice:

[image: test]

---

I am not good with CMOS modeling, but here's my tinkering based on your updates:

[image: test]

Two things to note: first, the voltage does not swing as in the pdf, and I blame my MOS switch for that, feel free to improve it as you see fit, and second, the supply voltage for the switch is referenced to a *negative* rail, with which the switch is supplied as its V<sub>EE</sub> -- to allow for the *negative* values of the waveform, `V(Vpz)`.

Comment: The Cbatt Shouldn't have initial condition for 2V

Comment: Is your switch directional?

Comment: @XM551 The paper says the battery has 2V, that's how I set it. The switch switches between two values: 1m\$\Omega\$ and 1M\$\Omega\$, so it's not unidirectional but the leakage when it's off doesn't matter, while it does conduct both ways when it's on. If you want it unidirectional, add `level=2 oneway` to its `.model` card and make sure the controlling voltage is at least one order of magnitude larger than `vt` (e.g. `vh=0.5 vt=-0.05` with pulse going from 0V to 1V).

Comment: @a concerned citizen i modify my question,and make the schematic "like " yours,however,my simulation is still not precharge the C1 to the negative or positive voltage first,but yours did

Comment: @XM551 Are you controlling sw1 and sw2 from the same source, and sw3 from the separate one? If so, you should take a closer look in my schematic, see where `c1` and `c2` go.

Comment: no Sw1 and sw3 are the same source,but the sw2 is from the separate one.sw3=Sg sw1=Spz

Comment: @XM551 Try changing the MOS with a real diode, for me even a 1N4148 worked (BAT54, too).

Comment: i can't do that,i simulate it in the virtuoso cadence,there is no 1N4148 diode in this software

Comment: I use the ideal diode now,but the simulation is still not the same as yours,mine didn't precharge.If the C1 wants to precharge,then it must have the charging loop ,so if the charging loop is negative to my switch,then the problem will come,that's why i wonder your ideal switch is no direction

Comment: @XM551 If you'll try to make the circuit practically, then you'll have to replace the switches with some sort of FETs, which will, most likely, have body diodes -- this will make them (quasi-)bidirectional. The switch in LTspice, as I mentioned in a previous comment, is bidirectional, unless you see `level=2 oneway` in the `.model` card (which is not, currently).

Comment: I found that your wave start from 1.xV at 0ms,but my start from 0V,why?our pulse and current source are the same

Comment: You're probably using something similar to `uic` (initial conditions), I let the solver determine the `.op`. If I had used with `uic`, it would have, most likely, started from zero (everything).

Comment: How to set up .op ?

Comment: I ask this question in another question,can you answer over there?my problem maybe more clear  than here.https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370950/why-this-point-in-this-schematic-will-begin-at-2v-at-0ms

Comment: @a concerned citizen.First,i can't use the ideal switch in my software,so i made common switch,TG switch.I think my TG switch is correct.However,our simulation are different,could you please make a TG switch,like mine,to replace your ideal switch to see wheather the simulation is still like that or not?so i can know where am i wrong.

Comment: @XM551 I tried and it doesn't go negative. I don't trust my MOS modeling skills, I searched online for some analog CMOS examples, and now the negative is approximately -0.5V. Since from 0 to -0.5 is an improvement, I have to say that a better modeling of the analog CMOS switch is the solution. Here is my last try: L=1u, W=10u, `.MODEL NMOS NMOS VTO=0.7, KP=110U,
+LAMBDA=0.04, GAMMA=0.4, PHI=0.7
.MODEL PMOS PMOS VTO=-0.7, KP=50U,
+ LAMBDA=0.05, GAMMA=0.5, PHI=0.8`

Comment: what are these ,.MODEL NMOS NMOS VTO=0.7, KP=110U, +LAMBDA=0.04, GAMMA=0.4, PHI=0.7 .MODEL PMOS PMOS VTO=-0.7, KP=50U, + LAMBDA=0.05, GAMMA=0.5, PHI=0.8,for?

Comment: @XM551 They're additional parameters passed on for the models. In LTspice, you can specify the length and width directly on the symbol's properties, then you can add a `.model` card with additional parameters. Looking over your recent pictures, it looks like you can directly specify these in the model, in Cadence. I forgot where I got them from, but it was a paper with basics for analog CMOS switches. You're welcome to use your own, if you think they can improve the simulation (actually, recommended).

Comment: but if i want to make this as a new ic,it is impossible to use "ideal" switch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76633/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-xm551).

Comment: @a concerned citizen Can you just try to modify the right capacitor,modify it to ic=0 ,to see wheather the wave is still the same or not?